# How to correctly using Spring profile on windows

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am trying to maintain different Spring profiles for development and production, for which I have created a folder(web skeleton) on my desktop with my Spring Boot project, application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties.

However, I am unable to import the profile into my project. The code that I use to import it to my project is as follows.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/web skeleton/application-dev.properties")
public class DevelopmentConfig {
@Bean
public  EmailService emailService(){
    return new MockEmailService();
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is the right way to use PropertySource in Spring.

Comment: Define "I'm unable", precisely. What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead?

Comment: I am trying to use JPA and I have written the configuration for using H2 database in the application-dev.properties file. However, the JPA is not creating the tables which I am expecting it to create. So I assumed it is due to the properties file not being imported.

Comment: That's quite a wild assumption. Adding a System.out.println() in your method (or simply using your debugger) would confirm or infirm that it's being called. Your JPA problem is most probably a different matter.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to debug it by printing it to my console. Can you please tell me if defining the @PropertySorce with the file path the way I have is the right way to do it on a windows machine. I am unable to find a good solution online.

Comment: I have no idea. Test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally define a custom source where we’re storing these properties, else the default location (classpath:application.properties) is looked up. So we now add the above annotations to the existing properties class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:configprops.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dev")
public class ConfigProperties {
    // previous code
}
```

Now any properties defined in the property file that has the prefix **dev** and the same name as one of the properties are automatically assigned to this object.

```
#Simple properties
dev.host=mailer@mail.com
dev.port=9000
```

Check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: This is correct.But,If he has to change the profile from dev to prod or cert then, he has to re-compile the code again and again. Which is not preferable.

Comment: To use external configuration files in your Maven build : configure the maven surefire plugin like this in your pom.xml:

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
     <argLine>-Dspring.config.location=file:${home}/conf/dev-external.properties
   </configuration>
</plugin>    

When running JUnit tests in IntelliJ:

    Run → Edit Configurations
    Defaults → JUnit
    add VM Options -> -ea -Dspring.config.location=file:${home}/conf/dev-external.properties

Comment: Or else just use environment variables such as ${home} and name the propertiy with the same name. For example application.proeprties

Comment: Hey guys. I have my configuration files in a different directory on my machine and not inside the project folder (i.e not the classpath). I want spring to fetch that file and initialize the JPA properties for me. I have it in in a separate directory since it has some critical information that I don't want to include in the project folder. Hence I am using "@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/web skeleton/application-dev.properties")".

Comment: I still don't understand why my code doesn't work when I use @Profile("dev") instead of @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="dev").

Answer (score 0):

I have done this kind of configuration too

Just add below code in your configuration class

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

And this propery in application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

you can change it to prod and cert as per you need.